# getting error ''AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find''' while crawling link in tr tag

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

tring to crawl link in table rows but failed to **scrape**.

code is below.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests

    r = requests.get('http://myneta.info/maharashtra2019/index.php?action=summary&subAction=candidates_analyzed&sort=candidate#summary')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

    div = soup.find('div',class_='divTableWithFloatingHeader')

    body = div.find('tbody')
    for links in body.find_all('tr'):
        link = links.find('a')
        print(link['href'])
```

plz help me anyne to crack this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that body.find_all('tr') return a sequence with None in it.
You can prevent the error by
adding `if links is not None:` statement

Comment: getting --- AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: so i suggested to put the errorness section under the if statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
>>> for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]: # [2:] is to skip 2 header rows
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        if tds:
            link = tds[0].find('a')
            print(f"{link['href']}")
```

---

**Output:**

```
index.php?action=summary&subAction=candidates_analyzed&sort=candidate#summary
index.php?action=summary&subAction=crime&sort=candidate#summary
index.php?action=summary&subAction=serious_crime&sort=candidate#summary
index.php?action=summary&subAction=crorepati&sort=candidate#summary
index.php?action=summary&subAction=education&sort=candidate#summary
index.php?action=summary&subAction=without_pan&sort=candidate#summary
index.php?action=summary&subAction=women_candidate&sort=candidate#summary
index.php?action=summary&subAction=candidates_analyzed&sort=candidate#summary
```

Comment: i am getting the links of candidates names in table rows.

Comment: @NiteshRao What do you need exactly?

Comment: i want links under all rows in -- div,"class_="TableWithFloatingHeader" --- table ,''styel":"padding: 0px;" --- tbody -- all tr -- td[2] links